# Evaluate Web Services Interceptor Before Spring Security Filter Chain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ws, ws-security

I have a SOAP-based web services application which is leveraging [Spring Web Services (and Spring WS Security)](https://spring.io/projects/spring-ws) as well as [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security). I am using a custom [AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/spring-ws-security/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.html) to authenticate the incoming requests (using an injected AuthenticationManager) and to add the successful authentications to the SecurityContext. I then have a custom AcessDecisionManager which is using a custom WebSecurityExpressionHandler to validate a certain property from the principal added to the context by the interceptor.

Below is an idea of what my configuration files look like:

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AccessDecisionManager customAccessDecisionManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
                cors()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .accessDecisionManager(customAccessDecisionManager)
                .antMatchers(GET, "/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().access("customAccessMethod()")
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

WebServiceConfig.java:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    ...

    ...


    @Bean
    AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor customAuthenticationInterceptor() {

        return new CustomAuthenticationInterceptor(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {

        interceptors.add(customAuthenticationInterceptor());
    }

}
```

The issue with this setup is that the Spring Security filter chain is evaluated first and fails the authentication because the AccessDecisionManager is evaluated before the request has a chance to enter the custom AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor and place the authentication in the SecurityContext.

Is there any way to evaluate the interceptor and handling of the request on the Web Services and WS Security side of things before it then hits the Spring Security filter chain? Is this a possibility?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: That simply will never happen. Why simply because servlet filters are executed before a servlet and it is the `MessageDispatcherServlet` that invokes the interceptors. So no there is no-way to do the interceptors before the filters.

Comment: Take a look at the [filters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-filters-review) section of the reference documentation. Note that you can add your own filter *inside* the filter chain instead of using an interceptor, e.g. `http.addFilter[Before|After](...)`.